# How to create the array of json objects(As value) with specified key on postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am logging data every time new entry is inserted into the table `EmployeeTimeRegisterations`. So, for that , I have created a trigger which is calling a function `logdatafunction` and I included the following code in my function

```
NewDataAfterUpdate varchar(10000);
sqlOperation := TG_OP::char;
IF (sqlOperation = 'I') THEN
        SELECT  
          json_agg(json_build_object(N.key, N.value, 'Type',A.data_type))::jsonb
        INTO 
          NewDataAfterUpdate
        FROM 
          json_each_text(to_json(NEW)) AS N
        JOIN
          (
            SELECT
                P.table_name,
                P.column_name,
                CASE WHEN (P.column_name = 'StartTime' OR P.column_name = 'StopTime') THEN 'Seconds' ELSE P.data_type END AS data_type
            FROM    
                (
                SELECT 
                    table_name,
                    column_name,
                    data_type 
                FROM 
                    information_schema.columns
                WHERE 
                    TABLE_NAME = TG_TABLE_NAME     
                ) AS P    
          ) AS A ON N.key = A.column_name;   
        INSERT INTO "AuditLogs" 
        VALUES (Id, sqlOperation ,session_user,TG_TABLE_NAME, CAST(NewDataAfterUpdate AS jsonb), CAST(to_json(OLD) AS jsonb), NEW."UpdatedBy", now() at time zone 'UTC', NEW."Id");            
    END IF;
```

The Data that is logged into the table `AuditLog` from above query is :

```
[
    {
        "Id": "271444bd-0a42-4a52-9336-300fe12f6a95",
        "Type": "uuid"
    },
    {
        "Type": "double precision",
        "SalesAmount": "0"
    },
]
```

But, I want to log it as

```
{
    "Id" : {
        "Value": "271444bd-0a42-4a52-9336-300fe12f6a95",
        "Type": "uuid"
    },
    "SalesAmount" : {
        "Value": "0",
        "Type": "double precision"
    }
}
```

Please Help me

Comment: Why do cast NewDataAfterUpdate to a varchar when you put a jsonb object in it? And then you cast is back to a jsonb object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the

```
json_agg(json_build_object(N.key, N.value, 'Type',A.data_type))::jsonb
```

with this :

```
json_object_agg(N.key, json_build_object('Value', N.value, 'Type',A.data_type))::jsonb
```

Solved my problem.